# fastest method of large file processing using concurrent futures python 3.5

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to grasp multithreading/multiprocessing using concurrent futures.

I have tried using the following sets of code. I understand that I will always have the disk IO problem, but I want to maximize my ram and CPU usage to the fullest extent possible.

What method is the most used/best method for large scale processing?

How do you use concurrent futures for processing large datasets?

Is there a more preferred method than the ones below?

Method 1:

```
for folders in os.path.isdir(path):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(pool.apply_async(process_largeFiles(folders)))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Method 2:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for folders in os.path.isdir(path):
        executor.submit(process_largeFiles(folders), 100)
```

Method 3:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for folders in os.path.isdir(path):
        executor.submit(process_largeFiles(folders), 10)
```

Should I attempt to  use process pool and thread pool together?

Method (thought):

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as process:
     with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as thread:
          for folders in os.path.isdir(path):
              process.submit(thread.submit(process_largeFiles(folders), 100),10)
```

What is the most efficient method to maximize my ram and cpu in the broadest use case?

I am aware that starting processes takes a bit of time, but would it be outweighed with the size of my files being processed?

Comment: Do you have any test data, functions that can be used to compare?  Have you done any comparison testing yourself? What were the results? What conclusions did you make?  It is a very broad question, with lots of unknowns that will affect the results of a comparison.

Comment: Do any of your solutions work at all?

Comment: Did you Profile the code to find out which parts are slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TreadPoolExecutor to open and read the files then use ProcessPoolExecutor to process the data.

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import deque

TPExecutor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
PPExecutor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
def get_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data

def process_large_file(s):
    return sum(ord(c) for c in s)

files = [filename1, filename2, filename3, filename4, filename5,
         filename6, filename7, filename8, filename9, filename0]

results = []
completed_futures = collections.deque()

def callback(future, completed=completed_futures):
    completed.append(future)

with TPExecutor(max_workers = 4) as thread_pool_executor:
    data_futures = [thread_pool_executor.submit(get_file, path) for path in files]
with PPExecutor() as process_pool_executor:
    for data_future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(data_futures):
        future = process_pool_executor.submit(process_large_file, data_future.result())
        future.add_done_callback(callback)
        # collect any that have finished
        while completed_futures:
            results.append(completed_futures.pop().result())
```

---

Used a done callback so it wouldn't have to wait for completed futures. I don't have any idea how that affects *efficiency* - used it mainly to simplify the logic/code in the `as_completed` loop.

If you need to throttle file or data submissions due to memory constraints it would need to be refactored. Depending file read time and processing time it is hard to say how much *data* will be in memory at any given moment.  I think gathering results in the `as_completed` should help mitigate that. `data_futures` may start completing while the ProcessPoolExecutor gets set up - that sequencing may need to be optimized.